# Unrecognised PYODBC Programming error message

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using PYODBC to write data to a Microsoft SQL Server database but I get the following:

`pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Unknown object type list during describe', 'HY000')`

Does anyone know what this could mean? I realise this is quite vague - however I can't find information on the error message anywhere.

Comment: Can you share an example of what you are attempting to write?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the SQL query, specifically a describe statement within the query. This error is just passing on the error thrown from the SQL serve

```
"Unknown object type list during describe"
```

without seeing the query I cant be any more specific about how to resolve this issue